# Is it possible to specify default images for scopes?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to set a default image for scopes? I've created a couple of scopes for Ubuntu Touch that are basically RSS scopes. But the sites they're reading from don't seem to always provide a highlighted image for their articles. The way the scope reads these by default leaves a space or an area marked X for the lack of image. **Is there a way I can specify that, say, the logo be used by default?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to provide a fallback image URL to the dash for display, through the scopes API currently.

You can however, have your scope download the images, and pass local `file:///` URIs to the dash for the image location, replacing any which were not usable with a URI pointing to the fallback image you wish to use instead.